# Problem loading activemerchant using Bundler

Tags: ruby, merb, activemerchant, bundler

I am using Merb. I can't seem to get activemerchant to load using Bundler. All my other gems load fine.

In my Gemfile I am using:

```
gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'
```

Here is the relevant error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizedNetGateway
```

Anyone run into this or have any ideas?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. The symbol that indicates the AuthorizeNetGateway changed in activemerchant. Just had to update my legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. The symbol that indicates the AuthorizeNetGateway changed in activemerchant. Just had to update my legacy code.